# Damage Cleanup and Toughness Boosting Effects

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose my opponent is playing Slivers, and has a [Muscle Silver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muscle%20Silver) and a [Metallic Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Metallic%20Sliver) on the field. On my side, I have a 1/1 Goblin token. My opponent declares both Slivers as attacking, and I block the Muscle Sliver with my Goblin. After combat, I Overload an [Electrickery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Electrickery), killing the Muscle Sliver. Since it took 1 damage and the +1/+1 from the [Muscle Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muscle%20Sliver) is removed, would the Metallic Sliver die?

Comment: Meant it to be a Muscle Sliver, not Might, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Aye, it seems to be the same situation. Thanks for the link!